# Firebase iOS - observe value listener not working properly

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var postData = [String]()
var Handle:DatabaseHandle?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    let database = Database.database().reference()


    Handle = database.child("Shifts").child("7 27").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
        let post = snapshot.value as? String
        if let actualPost = post{
            self.postData.append(actualPost)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

  }
```

I can't seem to get the data from the snapshot copied over to the postData properly. The snapshot contains the correct data. It is weird because if I changed the ".value" to ".childAdded" the code will do what it is supposed to, but I need to be looking at all of the values not just to see if something is added.

Thanks